# Key down keeps firing even after releasing the key

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, performance, keydown

I am handling keydown & key up event using jquery standard methods.If a key is pressed for few seconds & we release the key after some time then keydown keeps firing even after releasing it.Keyup is fired after quite long time or I can say when it finishes with all keydown firings.

What I want is when user releases the key keyup should fire immediately.

Here is the code

```
$( document ).on( 'keyup', function ( e ) {
        if (isCrossHairClicked)
        {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                        alert('hwaccel');
                    break;
                case 39:
                        alert('hwaccel');
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
        }
    });

$( document ).on( 'keydown', function ( e ) {

        if (isCrossHairClicked)
        {


            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37:
                    console.error('37 down');
                    break;
                case 39:
                    console.error('39 down');
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }
        }
    });
```

My console logs

```
"37 down" & "39 down"
```

keeps firing even after releasing the keys.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: .stop(true) in your javascript or jquery code. If you add your code, it would be helpful. But this is the solution

Comment: I can't see your `Code` ! :)

Comment: @GopsAB you mean i should use event.stop(true) in keydown handler?

Comment: Without your code, nothing is sure

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer myself.Putting `e.stopPropagation();`in keydown handler did the trick for me.